# How to show a form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to submit a form using popup or prompt window. Like I have a form I want to show in popup window how can I do it from JavaScript?

Comment: You can google tutorials...

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/karenhoney/9SC3V/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a form element using the function

```
  var x = document.createElement("form");
```

Then you need to attach that using something like appendChild

```
  var attachto = document.getElementbyId("contains_form");
  attachto.appendChild(x)
```

You need to fire the events that cause it.
Read this tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp